# How to force fsck on root filesystem on Voyage Linux

Tags: linux, debian-squeeze, fsck

I have a Voyage Linux (a Debian derived system) computer (which is headless, ie no display). The root filesystem is marked as corrupted and there are actually some errors.

I would like to fix these errors, but I can't.
I tried several things (shutdown -rF now, touch /forcefsck, set FSCKFIX=yes in /etc/default/rcS, tune2fs -c 1 -C 1 /myfilesystem): no check is done.

After some searches I discovered that the **/etc/init.d/checkroot.sh** was set to check the **/dev/root** filesystem:

```
   fstabroot=/dev/root
   #...
   rootcheck=yes
```

while **df** told me this:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                     3541948   1156324   2205660  35% /
/dev/disk/by-label/ROOT_FS 3541948   1156324   2205660  35% /
```

tune2fs indicates this:

```
# tune2fs -l /dev/disk/by-label/ROOT_FS
tune2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Filesystem volume name:   ROOT_FS
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype sparse_super large_file
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    (none)
Filesystem state:         not clean with errors
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Filesystem created:       Tue Mar 13 09:49:14 2012
Last mount time:          Sat Jan  1 02:36:20 2000
Last write time:          Tue Apr 14 08:38:22 2026
Mount count:              3
Maximum mount count:      1
Last checked:             Fri Jun 15 20:55:44 2012
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
```

My fstab looks like:

```
#/dev/hda1      /       ext2    defaults,noatime,rw     0       0
proc            /proc   proc    defaults                0       0
tmpfs       /tmp    tmpfs   nosuid,nodev        0   0
#tmpfs           /rw    tmpfs   defaults,size=32M       0       0
```

The only way I found to force fsck to run was to modify the /etc/init.d/checkroot.sh setting the following values:

```
   fstabroot=/dev/disk/by-label/ROOT_FS
   #...
   rootcheck=yes
```

and then perform `'touch /forcefsck'` and `reboot`

I believe this is a quick and dirty fix to make my FS be repaired.

What can I do to repair this volume using a better practice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a partition to be checked during boot, you have to turn on the sixth field - `fsckorder` bit ON in `/etc/fstab`. If you set that field to zero then fsck won't check the filesystem. For instance for the root(/) partition you can do this -

```
/dev/hda1      /       ext2    defaults,noatime,rw     0       1
```

Comment: My root partition is not mounted with fstab but by grub. I don't know if it is a good thing to mount it also in fstab. Is it ?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a good idea, have never worked with Voyage. You can add it to fstab once though and remove it once done. Or boot your machine in `single user mode`, remount root partition in rw mode, and do fsck. Then reboot it.

Comment: Voyage-Linux is a Debian derived distro. AFAIK, it works like a Debian. So could it be safe to add the following line to fstab ? `/dev/disk/by-label/ROOT_FS / ext2 defaults,noatime,rw 0 1` I am about to try but I don't know if it would cause a conflict with already mounted rootfs.

Comment: I made some tests and finally, this is the right solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that e2fsck cannot correct certain errors on the volume it is run from. This is why I always have a small additional Linux installation.

How do you make changes ("set FSCKFIX=yes in /etc/default/rcS") on a corropted filesystem?

Comment: The whole FS is not corrupted, so I just can edit many files. However, there are some errors on the FS that I cannot repair.

Comment: FSCKFIX=yes was already set and it was not that which prevented fsck to run at boot.